# Limit of HTML within XSL file

Tags: xml, xslt

Is there a limit(good practice) on the amount of HTML used within a XSL or can I have as much as I need in order to display the page correctly such as a simple menu bar?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XSLT stylesheet should generate XHTML from the input XML as you need it, but leave the styling to CSS.

You should use includes to add elements that every output requires (such as a header, navigation bar or footer).

XSLT is supposed to transform XML data to useful XHTML (if output format is `html`). I can't see why the amount of elements from the xsl-namespace compared to (xhtml-)elements without namespace should matter.

Comment: Thanks for the above @CoDEmaX, howwever I am still confused. What I don't understand is how XSLT generates XHTML from XML. I have at the moment 3 files, products.xml, products_style.css and products.xsl. The products.xml contains the link to the xsl file and the transformation occurs if I use Netbeans. Using the XSL transformation it generates a xhtml page. But without using Netbeans when I open the page products.xml in the browser I can see a formatted page but the source code is still xml. Should the transformation that occurs in the browser display the source code as xhtml or xml?

Comment: Browsers come with their own XSLT transformation engine and may format XML files automatically (they might look for an *.xsl or *.xslt file with same name). The source file remains XML, the source code in the browser should be XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

If the aim of the XSLT is to output HTML then of course you can put it as many HTML result elements as you need or want.